# How to map a function over 2 lists? [Syntactic Analysis]

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists

```
words = {"the", "man", "hit", "the", "table"}  
grammarTerminal = {{N,"man"},{N,"woman"},{N,"table"},{D,"the"},{D,"a"},{V,"hit"}}
```

and a function

```
lexicalRules[grammarTerminal_,word_] := Cases[grammarTerminal, {x_,word}];
```

I want to make a function which gets:
`{{{D, "the"}, {N, "man"}, {V, "hit"}, {D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}}`
when the function takes `grammarTerminal` and `words` as arguments and uses `lexicalRules`

I tried something like `Map[lexicalRules[grammarTerminal,x_],words]` but it didn't work.

Is there a simple way to achieve this using `Map`?

Comment: Try `First[Cases[grammarTerminal, {_, #}]] & /@ words`.

Comment: Not an answer, but you might be interested in a new feature introduced in 10.3: `TextStructure["The man hits the table", "ConstituentString"]` yields: `{"(Sentence, ((Noun Phrase, (Determiner, The), (Noun, man)), (Verb Phrase, (Verb, hits), (Noun Phrase, (Determiner, the), (Noun, table)))))"}`

Comment: `lexicalRulesAlt[x_: grammarTerminal] :=  Function[y, Select[x, MemberQ[#, y] &]]` and Flatten /@ lexicalRulesAlt[] /@ words, or Flatten /@ lexicalRulesAlt[grammarTerminalAlt]/@ words

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were very close. All it takes is turning your function to be mapped into a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html):

```
Map[lexicalRules[grammarTerminal, #] &, words]
(* {{{D, "the"}}, {{N, "man"}}, {{V, "hit"}}, {{D, "the"}}, {{N, "table"}}} *)
```

Here's another [pure function tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
 Extract[grammarTerminal, Map[Position[grammarTerminal[[All, 2]], #] &, words]]
```

> {{D, "the"}, {N, "man"}, {V, "hit"}, {D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}